# AngularCli - Unable to find plugin: videoJsResolutionSwitcher

Tags: angular, plugins, angular-cli, video.js

VideoJs is not able to recognize VideoJs-Resolution-Switcher as a Plugin!

**Errors**: 
-  *Angular2 - Unable to find plugin: videoJsResolutionSwitcher* 
- player.updateSrc is not a function

---

Library: 
- videojs: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/ 
- videojs-resolution-switcher: https://github.com/kmoskwiak/videojs-resolution-switcher

**What I did?** 
 1. Installed videojs, videojs-resolution-switcher and the types for VideoJs: `npm install --save @types/videojs`
 2. I'm loading globally the plugin on angular.cli on **scripts** section.

```
"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/video.js/dist/video.min.js",
        "../node_modules/videojs-contrib-hls/dist/videojs-contrib-hls.min.js",
        "../node_modules/videojs-resolution-switcher/lib/videojs-resolution-switcher.js"
      ]
```

3. Following this basic setup: https://kmoskwiak.github.io/videojs-resolution-switcher
 4. I receive those errors: 
-  Unable to find plugin: videoJsResolutionSwitcher 
- player.updateSrc is not a function

[Similiar Question - Unable to find plugin: videoJsResolutionSwitcher in angular2-universal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594548/unable-to-find-plugin-videojsresolutionswitcher-in-angular2-universal)

---

**1. Should I need to [initialize the plugin](http://docs.videojs.com/docs/guides/plugins.html#how-should-i-use-the-video-js-icons-in-my-plugin)? Or is it just initialized?**
- The Plugin is just initialized at the end of the script!
   `videojs.plugin('videoJsResolutionSwitcher', videoJsResolutionSwitcher);`
**2. How can I declare this plugin in a controller? Since my controller doesn't reconize this videoJsResolutionSwitcher**

```
const options = {
  'autoplay': false,
  'controls': true,
  'plugins': {
    'videoJsResolutionSwitcher': {
      'default': 'low',
      'dynamicLabel': true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on how I was impoting the Video.js library in my controller!

That's looks to be the wrong way
 `import * as videojs from "videojs";`

Instead I used
 `declare videojs;` without the need to declare the plugin too!